# Pyaudio doesn't work when I try to run the code on windows

Tags: python, installation, pyaudio

This is my code but when I start to code I get error. I installed pip and the other function but error occurs

import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:

```
print("Speak Anything: ")
audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    text=r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("You said:()".format(text))
except:
    print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

And also this is my error. I tried a lot of solution but nothings work.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 3, in 
with sr.Microphone() as source:
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 79, in **init**
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: Have you installed the module you are using

Comment: I installed module with cmd

Comment: The error shows that `pyaudio` is not installed. Btw what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using pycharm

Comment: Install pyaudio in pycharm

Comment: It is the same error I faced recently. But when I installed those libraries in pycharm, they works fine

Comment: I try to install pyaudio in pycharm but the other errors occur   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\asus\pycharmprojects\pythonproject2\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bg96zqe_\\pyaudio_491ff5ba01414
c32a6276a1aaed50b6e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bg96zqe_

Comment: This is just head of errors, it continues

Comment: Please send some last lines of error

Comment: Make sure your Internet connection is on when installing Pyaudio

Comment: I have read some information about pyaudio, this libary is not working after Python 3.7. Is it true?

Comment: if your `python` version is `3.7` go for wheel file installation you can find related post on SO!

Comment: Also I'm using python version 3.9, can you explain to me a little bit what should I do?

Comment: I also have python `3.9` but it works fine for me @Yagizefe

Answer (score 0):

As you mention your `python` version is `3.9` you can find associate wheel file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Let me give you example from image as you can see my python version is 3.7 so i will download `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` which contains only python 3.7

[image]

1. `cp37m‑win_amd64` which means `python 3.7` with `64 bit` and verify from image
2. Now i will download that file and give full path where i have downloaded and use as
   `pip install path-to-wheel-file`
3. so now you have to do for `python 3.9` and check it is `32 bit` or `64 bit` and download wheel file and install `pyaudio`